# Can an argument contain a metacharacter?

Tags: bash

Is there a way that an argument mentioned in a [manual to man command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) in the description of the synopsis (I quote "italic text replace with appropriate argument.") contains a metacharacter without escaping it? One would say from the definition of an argument mentioned for example in Tom Ryder's *Bash quick start guide* (ISBN 978-1-78953-408-5, page 21), that metacharacters divide arguments (at least for space), but in bash scripting, I have seen for example opening and closing square brackets used the way I would say, they are part of an argument. For example this script: `NUMBER='^[0-9]+$'`.

Comment: Which metacharacters are you talking about? You can set your `IFS` to some metacharacter, but I doubt you'll get happy with a backslash as separator …

Comment: And in what context? Arguments to what? Passed by whom?

Comment: You can quote a string that contains whitespace with `'` (single-quote) characters or with `"` (double-quote) characters.  Then `bash` will see the string as a single command-line item rather than multiple items.

Comment: @Philippos I am talking about whatever metacharacter. This is not a question of how to escape metacharacter from interpretation. This is a question of whether there is such an option. I am sorry I don't know what you mean by IFS.

Comment: I've got a feeling you don't actually understand what you're asking. Could you provide an example please? A shell code snippet?

Comment: If you mean the definition in the Bash man page: "metacharacter: A character that, when unquoted, separates words.  One of the following: `|  & ; ( ) < >` space tab newline", then the answer would rather directly be "no", just based on the definition. On the other hand, if you include, say, glob characters (e.g. `[]*?`), or stuff like `{}!#` that are _sometimes_ special, then the answer could be "sometimes, it depends".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @terdon what context? I don't understand, what you are asking about. Arguments in general, e.g. those defined in POSIX 3.21 [Base definitions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov that could be. I am not an English native speaker, nor a professional in Bash. Well, I have seen this script `if [[ "$#" -ne "3" ]]; then`. I would assume that opening and closing square brackets might be metacharacters (at least regarding POSIX). And I wonder where there are arguments in that line.

Comment: Arguments to what - the `bash` command or commands that `bash` calls? What type of "metacharacters" - shell globbing chars, or regexp chars, or shell language chars, or something else? If you use proper quoting then you don't need to escape any of them, assuming by "escape" you mean put a backslash in front of it. For example if you pass `'if [[ "$#" -ne "3" ]]; then'` to a shell script then that script will see it as a single argument, no escaping required.

Comment: @ilkkachu I think you have answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Juandev, added as an actual answer and elaborated a bit

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, I think that the major problem with my question was that I haven't got an idea, of which metacharacters bash recognizes and that `[]` are not a metacharacter for Bash. My problem is not escaping or deescaping metacharacters of glob characters but understanding what is an argument in a command line and how to recognize it. Whether there are some characters, which may indicate the end of an argument or it is not the case.

Comment: I was asking if you meant arguments given to bash itself, or arguments passed to a bash script, or maybe arguments of command being executed in a bash environment. The first version of your question gave no context so we couldn't know what you mean when you say "argument".

Comment: @terdon no problem, I am happy I could somehow elaborate on the question, so that it's understandable to more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Metacharacter" is a somewhat fuzzy term, I think.

Bash's man page does give it a strict meaning:

> metacharacter: A character that, when unquoted, separates words. One of the following: `|  & ; ( ) < >` space tab newline"

so if you mean that, and arguments passed to commands started from the shell, then the answer would rather directly be "no", just based on the definition.

On the other hand, sometimes the word is used for other special characters too. And if you include, say, glob characters (e.g. `[]*?`), or stuff like `{}!#$` that are sometimes special, then the answer could be "sometimes".

---

In concrete, something like `ls blahblah?*[123].txt` will, in POSIX-like shells by default, call `ls` with the argument `blahblah?*[123].txt` if there are no files that match that glob pattern. (If there are, their names will be expanded instead. And zsh and csh will just complain, unless asked otherwise) And while `{` starts brace expansion in shells that support it, it's only special if the rest of the word also fits the syntax of brace expansion. `ls {` just passes the single argument `{`, but `ls foo{a,b}` passes the two args `fooa`, `foob`. And `$` might or might not trigger some expansion, depending on what comes after. `echo foo$` prints `foo$`, but `echo foo<` gives an error.

The major point here is that `|&;()<>` are special to the shell's lexer, and so are recognized earlier during the command line processing, while `*?[]$` are only recognized after the command line is initially divided into words. `!` and `#` are somewhat more special yet, in that (if history expansion and comments are enabled), they get recognized even earlier. But they're not metacharacters in the same sense since they don't have an effect in the lexer phase. `echo foo! foo#` prints `foo! foo#`.

That `[[`? It's just an odd-looking keyword, similar to `if`, `while` etc. Or indeed `{`. (try `type if`, `type {`, `type [[`.) It's a keyword that affects parsing inside it, but it's not composed of metacharacters, `echo [[` still prints `[[`. Compare with `((`, where `echo ((` is an error. (and `type ((` doesn't work, and `type "(("` gives nothing useful)

Though, I'm not sure it's too useful to go too deep in the shell's syntax, it's hairy, and it smells a bit odd in there. Also, I may have made mistakes with the terminology or other things above.

Comment: So we may say that for the bash shell special characters are not part of an argument, while for other shells it might be true? For example `[]` are not a bash shell special character, but it might be a special character for other shells as mentioned in POSIX documentation.

Comment: @Juandev, nooo. Many of those special characters are special _in some contexts_, in Bash and in others. `[]` are special in that they're glob characters. They're just not special in the same way `|&;()<>` (plus space,tab,newline) are.

Comment: As for that `NUMBER='^[0-9]+$'` you mentioned, there, those characters are quoted, so none of them are special. Not that those are special in that context anyway (because it's a scalar assignment, and there's no globbing, and nothing after the `$` so it's not an expansion), so `NUMBER=^[0-9]+$` would work the same. But `NUMBER=^<0-9>+$` wouldn't be the same as `NUMBER='^<0-9>+$'`.

Comment: OK, now I understand.